# PLC ladder-logic equation stabilization

Tags: plc, ladder

I have worked with PLCs in the past. Now, I'm working with devices called 'vital-logic controllers'. The vital logic controllers are similar to PLCs, but I'm wondering about a subtlety of how the ladder-logic is evaluated in PLCs compared to vital-logic controllers.

In PLCs, my understanding is that one 'tick' represents one pass through the equations; every gate is updated once with respect to its inputs. This does *not*  guarantee that the change-of-inputs has propagated to the outputs. Therefore, a PLC may require several system-ticks for the outputs to stabilize w.r.t. the inputs.

In contrast, I have been told that vital-logic controllers execute the ladder-logic *repeatedly*, within one system tick, in order to force the change-of-inputs to propogate all the way to the outputs in one tick.

So, my question is:

- Am I correct PLC systems-ticks just update each gate once, and do not attempt to stabilize the equations?
- Is my colleage correct that vital-logic controllers repeatedly execute their ladder-logic equations until the outputs have stabilized?

---

Update to answer comments.

1) Yes, by 'vital-logic' I am referring to railway signalling controllers where fail-safe operation must be guaranteed.

2) I have been unable to find a manual for a vital-logic controller covering this level of detail. I'll get in touch with the manufacturers.

3) By 'tick', I meant 'program scan'. I am basically asking if there is any difference between the program-scan operation in a PLC, compared to a vital-logic controller.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what a 'vital-logic controller' is and add a link to a datasheet or user manual. I have only heard the word 'vital' used like this in the context of railway signalling where fail-safe must be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a chance to directly ask the vendors (Alstom, Hitachi) at a trade-show (RSSI) about this. Surprisingly, both vendors confirmed that they do use the technique I described. Specifically, both vendors described their vital-logic execution model as:

- Execute each vital-logic equation up to 5 times
- If the equation has not stabilized after 5 iterations, throw an error

Unfortunately, it's very difficult to dig up anything like a data-sheet which describes this behavior. Both vendors used slightly different terminology to describe this function.

Answer (score 4):

> In PLCs, my understanding is that one 'tick' represents one pass through the equations; every gate is updated once with respect to its inputs.

I've been working with PLCs for over 30 years but never heard of 'tick' used in that context. Most use the term 'program scan' and over the years program scan-times have dropped from around 20 ms to < 1 ms. In general a simple PLC works as follows:

- Read the inputs. Most will make a snapshot copy of the inputs and execute the logic based on the snapshot to ensure that each logic equation sees the same input status. This is important because, unlike relay logic, the PLC logic is executed sequentially rather than in parallel.
- Execute the logic, updating the internal registers including the output map.
- Write the outputs.
- Do any housekeeping.
- Repeat.

We'll have a look at the vital logic when you supply some details.

> This does not guarantee that the change-of-inputs has propagated to the outputs. Therefore, a PLC may require several system-ticks for the outputs to stabilize w.r.t. the inputs.

No. The outputs are updated at the end of the scan. Obviously if timers or counters are used there will be a delay in the output response. The other thing is that if an output depends on a condition that will only be true further down the program then that output won't turn on until the following scan. This may be what you are thinking of.

---

[image]

*Figure 1. A rather quaint mix of old and new from [Μίνθα: A Framework for Auto-Programming and Testing of Railway Controllers for Varying Clients](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/716a/c6f19f60e6cc73642b997ced068a74eec21c.pdf).*

The image of Figure 1 shows a controller much like any other except for what it is controlling. SSI, solid-state interlocking was becoming more popular on British Rail when I left Irish Rail but I never worked on any of it. Wikipedia's [Solid-state interlocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_State_Interlocking) says:

> SSI utilises a 2-out-of-3 redundancy architecture, whereby all safety-critical functions are performed in three separate processing lanes and the results voted upon. An SSI interlocking cubicle comprises three Interlocking Processors or Multi Processor Modules (MPMs), two Panel Processors and a Diagnostics Processor (DMPM). An SSI system can operate on two MPMs in the event of the failure of one. It does not need the DMPM to function as an interlocking, as this drives the technician's terminal only.

Back to your question:

> I have been told that vital-logic controllers execute the ladder-logic repeatedly, within one system tick, in order to force the change-of-inputs to propagate all the way to the outputs in one tick.

This seems unlikely.

- I think the program would have to scan through the compiled control tables in a sequential manner.
- Railway signalling doesn't have to update all that quickly. As the leading axle of a train passes a signal it will turn red. A one second delay isn't going to cause any trouble.

The big problems will be ensuring that a processor bug doesn't cause the same problem across all redundant systems. For this reason they may choose processors from a variety of lots or vendors and execute a transformed program (think of de Morgan's equivalent of the logic) in one of the controllers. The other aspect to bear in mind is that the monitoring unit needs a short time delay before reacting to a mismatch in outputs.

This week I was debugging an industrial control solid-state safety circuit (Omron components) and out of curiousity I monitored the dual-channel safety circuit that monitors the machine safety doors. As I expected, every 200 ms the 24 V source signal is switched off for 0.5 ms and if this is not detected by the corresponding input the safety input faults out. Meanwhile the other channel is doing the same test with 100 ms offset. This type of checking will detect open or short-circuits in the safety wiring but, most importantly, it will detect an input stuck "on" due to a failed semi-conductor on the safety controller input.

It's a fascinating topic.

Comment: Thanks - this answers one half of my question. I will try to chase down a detailed manual.